# Protege OWL API loading ontologies with URI

Tags: java, uri, protege, owl-api

I'm working with the Protege OWL API in a java program and am having a problem loading my ontologies. When I try a URI, it works. However, when I try to use a local path on my computer, it doesn't work.

```
 package Test;

 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaOWLModel;

 public class  TestLoad {
    public static JenaOWLModel Model =null;
    public static String URI="http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/travel/travel.owl";          
    // change the URI by this "C:/Users/Sara/Desktop/travel.owl"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Model=ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(URI);
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {   
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: To improve your question please describe how exactly your program doesn't work, e,g, it throws an error (which error) or list other symptoms.

Comment: it goes directly to the catch in my consol i have the string Error  as the println (no exceptions are thrown)

Comment: my program use this file to have the classes defined in this file so when i do the URI it work perfectly but when i use the local path i can't have the classes i just put a part of my code i can put my whole code if that would help

Comment: Print the stack trace instead. Exception.printStackTrace() will do

Comment: Made some small grammar and formatting improvements (white space) to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you're using is not a complete URI because `C:` is not a protocol.
Prefix the string with `file:///`and you should get better results.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help